# Logitech DiNovo Mini not working

Tags: centos, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a logitech DiNovo Mini (Bluetooth) keyboard that worked when I first installed it onto my Centos7 system, but not on subsequent bootups.

lsusb shows the bluetooth USB transceiver:

```
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 046d:c71f Logitech, Inc. diNovo Mini Wireless Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 046d:c71e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:0b07 Logitech, Inc
```

but the bluetoothctl command does not see any bluetooth controllers.  Is that the problem?  (And how do I fix that)

Comment: Please edit your qeuestion with the output of `dmesg` that appears after you plug in the USB transceiver.